# ValueError: Protocol message SsdFeatureExtractor has no field replace_preprocessor_with_placeholder

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection-api

I'm using an object-detection API to train my own model, but while running the training using this command:

`python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco.config`

I get this error:

`WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\MHD\Anaconda3\envs\tf15\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py:124: main (from __main__) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use object_detection/model_main.py.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "train.py", line 179, in <module>
tf.app.run()
File "C:\Users\MHD\Anaconda3\envs\tf15\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 124, in run
_sys.exit(main(argv))
File "C:\Users\MHD\Anaconda3\envs\tf15\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\deprecation.py", line 136, in new_func
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "train.py", line 175, in main
graph_hook_fn=graph_rewriter_fn)
File "C:\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\legacy\trainer.py", line 249, in train
detection_model = create_model_fn()
File "C:\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py", line 119, in build
return _build_ssd_model(model_config.ssd, is_training, add_summaries)
File "C:\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py", line 237, in _build_ssd_model
is_training=is_training)
File "C:\tensorflow1\models\research\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py", line 187, in _build_ssd_feature_extractor
if feature_extractor_config.HasField('replace_preprocessor_with_placeholder'):
ValueError: Protocol message SsdFeatureExtractor has no field replace_preprocessor_with_placeholder`

please help me guys

Answer (score 0):

Tracing down the cause of this error, I found the option `replace_preprocessor_with_placeholder` was recently added. Here is the commit [record.](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/commit/0558408514dacf2fe2860cd72ac56cbdf62a24c0) (On that page if you search for `replace_preprocessor_with_placeholder` you will find that it was added recently on March 7th, 2019).

So the cause of the error is obviously your proto files version is not consistent with the code version. If you compare `object_detection/protos/ssd.proto` on your local machine and on the github repo, you will probably find this [line](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/b4b8c723d377caae2f4243cf8fc711eab71736a1/research/object_detection/protos/ssd.proto#L191) does not exist on your local machine's file (because this filed was also added recently!).

The easiest way to fix this error is to reinstall the **object detection api** following this [guide](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md).

Since you already have all packages installed, essentially there are two steps you need to do, install the coco api and compile the protobuff. A new protobuff compilation will fix your error.

Also I recommend you follow the latest api tutorial, I see in your call you are using `train.py`, this file has now been put in the legacy folder and is not recommended to run since they may not be up-to-date.